# Notation for Partials

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

Let $u=s+t$ and $v=s^2+t^2$ how do I find $\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial u}\right)_v$ and $\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial v}\right)_u?$

The notation is confusing to me and the book didn't elaborate. I know the first notation is saying to take the partial of $t$ with respect to $u$ with $v$ held constant, but that will only make sense if $t$ was a function of those two independent variables. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would substitute $s$ from the first equation into the second, and then implicitly differentiate.

Since $u=s+t$, then $s=u-t$. 
So $$\begin{align}v &= (u-t)^2 + t^2 \\ v&= u^2 - 2ut + 2t^2 \tag1\end{align}$$

Now we take the partial derivative of $(1)$ with respect to $u$. **But**, remember that $t$ is a function of $u$ and $v$. Account for that.
$$
\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial{u}}v &= \frac{\partial}{\partial{u}}u^2 - \frac{\partial}{\partial{u}}(2ut) + \frac{\partial}{\partial{u}}(2t^2) \\
0& = 2u - \left(2u\cdot\frac{\partial t}{\partial{u}} + 2t\right) + 4t \frac{\partial t}{\partial{u}} \tag2\end{align}$$

Look at that. Now all we have to do is solve for $\frac{\partial t}{\partial{u}}$ in $(2)$.

Similarly, we can find $\frac{\partial t}{\partial{v}}$.

Also as a note, the subscript $v$ in $\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial u}\right)_v$ indicates that we take the partial derivative of $\frac{\partial t}{\partial u}$ with respect to $v$.
After finding those, we will find that $$\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial u}\right)_v = \left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial v}\right)_u.$$

Comment: How did you get $$0 = 2u - \left(2u\cdot\frac{\partial t}{\partial{u}} + 2t\right) + 4t \frac{\partial t}{\partial{u}}?$$ Specifically, $2u\cdot\frac{\partial t}{\partial u}+2t$? Was that by the product rule? Which is why you emphasized, "But, remember that t is a function of u and v. Account for that." ?

Comment: Yes, precisely the product rule! Also careful with the minus signs in front of the products. I left the parentheses, but many times students forget to distribute it.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. If we are taking only the partial with respect to $u$ then why would $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(2t^2)=4t?$

Comment: That's because of the chain rule. Remember that $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$. The same rule applies.

The outer function $f$ is $2(\ \ )^2$. The inner function is $t(u,v)$.

Comment: Oh, since we are treating $t$ as a function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yup. The chain rule and product rule still apply because $t(u,v)$ is a function. It's the same as using implicit differentiation to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in an expression like $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. The partial just indicates our function is a multivariate function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17420/discussion-between-andrey-and-robben).

Answer (score 0):

Is there any restriction on $t$? What I did was squaring both sides of the first equation to obtain $u^2=s^2+2st+t^2$. Combining with the 2nd equation gives $t=\frac{u^2-v}{2s}$. From the first equation, we could rewrite this as $t=\frac{u^2-v^2}{2(u-t)}$. To make $t$ the subject, we proceed by completing the square.